# The exponential generating functions are a ring?

Tags: generating-functions, formal-power-series

It is clear that proving that the power series $\sum a_nx^n$ is a ring implies that the ordinary generating functions are also a ring.

My doubt is, the exponential generating $\sum a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$   functions are also a ring?  How do I justify this knowing the above?

Comment: Check the axioms. Is it an abelian group under addition? Is the multiplication closed? does distributivity apply?

Comment: Or, alternatively, Substitute $a'_n=\frac{a_n}{n!}$ into the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are really asking is the following.

Suppose given a ring $R$. The set of all sequences $(a_0,a_1,\dots)$
of elements in $R$ forms a vector space over $R$. Let multiplication
be defined by $a\star b = c$ where $c_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}.$
The vector space now becomes a ring isomorphic to the ring of formal
power series in $R$ given by the ordinary generating function map.

Now define another multiplication on the vector space by
$a\ast b = c$ where now instead $c_n := \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a_kb_{n-k}.$ The vector space now becomes a ring isomorphic to
the ring of formal power series in $R$ except the mapping is by
exponential generating function.

Comment: Exactly, the isomorphisms do hold?